# import cx_oracle error in ipython with Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, ipython, cx-oracle

When I run in `python`

```
import cx_Oracle
```

It's successful.

**But, when I run in `ipython`, it will raise a error:**

```
In [1]: import cx_Oracle
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d1ecebcba3d2> in <module>()
----> 1 import cx_Oracle

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/roy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
Referenced from: /Users/roy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
Reason: image not found
```

---

The following is my env:

```
Mac OSX EL Capitan 10.11.1
Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)
ipython 3.2.0
instantclient-basic-macos.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
cx_Oracle 5.2
```

---

And, these are steps of installation: [Build and Install cx_Oracle on Mac Leopard Intel](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csSpring2012/cs327/cx_mac.html)

These items are added to `.bash_profile`:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/Users/roy/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.  Did you ever figure out why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Also, fwiw, it works fine in Jupyter Notebook for me.  So the only problem is with IPython.

Comment: @user1507844 I have resolved it. Just Turning Off Rootless System Integrity Protection. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved it. Just Turning Off Rootless System Integrity Protection.
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11

Comment: That seems a tad dramatic.  I'd like to find a way to get this working without turning off a security feature that it seems Apple makes pretty difficult to turn off.  Going to keep this bounty open to see if someone has a cleaner answer.